# How do I swap my app between desktop mode and Modern UI mode?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, desktop-application

I noticed that both Internet Explorer 10 and Google Chrome 23 (? and up) have the ability to switch between desktop and Modern UI (aka Metro) modes from within the application. I have been trying to determine how this is done. My guess is that this may work using protocol handlers. My searches through [the Chromium source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/source/search) have proved unfruitful thus far so I thought I'd pitch it to the community and see if I can get a definitive answer on how to do this. In the meantime, I'll continue searching elsewhere as always.

So, how does one write an application that has both desktop and Modern UI variants with the ability, inside the application, to switch between the two?